# Power e in RSA-encryption algorithm

Tags: totient-function

I'm busy with the RSA-encryption algorithm. I figured out why $0≤C≤25$ and $ ∈ {2,3,...,m−2}$ But I can't find why $ ∈ {2, 3, ... ,  ( − 2)}$ in the RSA-encryption algorithm with $C≡P^e(modn)$?

Comment: Could you link to a reference with expanded terminology?

Comment: no, just found it in a presentation of my maths teacher

Comment: I mean, is C the ciphertext here... P the message post padding process? etc

Comment: Yes, P is plaintext, C is ciphertext

Comment: The $0 \leq C \leq 25$ constraint is not for RSA: at least, not usually.  For the part of the question that is relevant to RSA, I'm a bit skeptical about the $\varphi(n-2)$ upper bound.  Usually, in RSA key generation the upper bound is $\varphi(n)$ and $\varphi(n-2)$ may be larger than $\varphi(n)$.  For instance, $\varphi(21)=12<18=\varphi(19)$.  As noted below, the mandatory condition is $\gcd(\varphi(n),e)=1$, and many implementations use $e=2^{16}+1=65537$, which is prime and not too large.  If that $e$ divides $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ new $p$ and $q$ are chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** needed, it is just common sense. Why would make $e$ larger than necessary? Even your range can made smaller if you use the Carmichael function $\lambda(n),$ see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation) or [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017).

What you really need is $\gcd(\varphi(n),e)=1$ in order to compute the decryption exponent
with $e d \equiv 1 \bmod{\varphi(n)}$